# Outlook calendar events after reinstalling windows

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I reinstailled my windows, but totally forgot about the Outlook calendar events. The ones I got invited to are fine, as I can just accept them again. My problem is with the ones I invited others to, as I cannot accept them, cannot copy them to my calendar, as it was "Organized by me".

Do you know how to copy these to my calendar?

[Cannot accept own event, and it is not in my calendar either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC6RK.png)

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you are not using Exchange email account right? As I know, calendar items for Exchange account should be able to synced.

For IMAP/POP account, you may try to log in to your web mail and see if you can find those those meeting invitation messages in your Sent folders. I tested with Gmail account in my environment, if you can indeed find them, you could just download the .ics file and import it to your Outlook desktop client.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, upon opening the .ics my Outlook opens, and gives the following error: "We couldn't find this meeting in the calendar. It may have been moved or deleted". If I try to open it with the calendar app, I get the following error: "Couldn't open event It's possible the calendar file is corrupted

Comment: Can it be successfully imported to other email account's calendar in Outlook?